# Ruby: cleaner returns from loop iteration methods

Tags: ruby, methods, return-value, enumerable

I find that I frequently have methods that iterate through an enumerable in order to return a different enumerable or a hash. These methods almost always look like this simplistic example:

```
  def build_hash(array)
    hash = {}
    array.each do |item|
      hash[ item[:id] ]= item
    end
    hash
  end
```

This approach works works, but I've often wondered if there's a cleaner way to do this, specifically without having to wrap the loop in a temporary object so that the return is correct.

Does anyone know of an improved and/or cleaner and/or faster way to do this, or is this pretty much the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few ways, considering your specific example

```
arr = [{:id => 1, :name => :foo}, {:id => 2, :name => :bar}]

Hash[arr.map{ |o| [o[:id], o] }]
arr.each_with_object({}){ |o, h| h[o[:id]] = o }
arr.reduce({}){ |h, o| h[o[:id]] = o; h }
arr.reduce({}){ |h, o| h.merge o[:id] => o }

# each of these return the same Hash
# {1=>{:id=>1, :name=>:foo}, 2=>{:id=>2, :name=>:bar}}
```

Comment: Great suggestions, Kyle. I was sort of aware of these methods but hadn't realized how useful they could be. Thanks for the examples!

Comment: @Andrew you're welcome. [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) is your friend!

Comment: `group_by` will not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case, you can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and do something like this :

```
def build_hash(array)
  array.inject({}) { |init, item| init[item[:id]] = item; init }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{}.tap { |h| array.each { |a| h[a[:id]] = a } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is also a way how to convert `Array` into `Hash`.

```
list_items = ["1", "Foo", "2", "Bar", "3" , "Baz"]

 hss = Hash[*list_items]
```

- parameters must be even, otherwise a fatal error is raised, because an odd
  number of arguments can’t be mapped to a series of key/value pairs.

> {"1"=>"Foo", "2"=>"Bar", "3"=>"Baz"}

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveSupport's [`index_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by).

Your example becomes trivial:

```
def build_hash(array)
  array.index_by{|item| item[:id]}
end
```

There is no really great way to build a hash in Ruby currently, even in Ruby 2.0.

You can use `Hash[]`, although I find that very ugly:

```
def build_hash(array)
  Hash[array.map{|item| [item[:id], item]}]
end
```

If [we can convince Matz](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7292), you could at least:

```
def build_hash(array)
  array.map{|item| [item[:id], item]}.to_h
end
```

There are [other requests](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4151) for [new ways](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6669) to create hashes.

Comment: Wow, I was actually just reading your remarks on enumerable #to_h the other day, what a fun coincidence that you found my SO question :) Thanks, Marc!